# EF 6.13 add-migration throw exception on VS2017, Microsoft.Build.Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I get this error when i typing add migration. The ApplicationDbContext exists in another project while migration file exist in the web application project.

If I remember right it has worked before but now it stopped to work.
I have tried restart visual studio, run it as administrator. reinstall EF 6.11, 6.13 and 6.20.

Visual Studio Version 15.8.5, Build Tool 15.1

The migration exists in the startup project and the package manager is also set on the startup project.

I have even tried to repair Visual Studio and after I also tried uninstall and then install but nothing works.

I tried the the solution where I edit devenv.exe.config which did not work
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/382

```
add-migration AddedUserFax
    System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Company.SoftwareX.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
       at Company.SoftwareX.Database.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Company.SoftwareX.Database.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext..ctor() in C:\Projects\Visual Studio\Project\Company.SoftwareX.Database\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line 110
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
       at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
       at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
    The type initializer for 'Company.SoftwareX.Database.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext' threw an exception.
```

Comment: You have static properties/ a static constructor in the class `Company.SoftwareX.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext` that are causing these errors.

Comment: ... i.e. you should reproduce these static initializers in your question.

Comment: @spender wow thank you.

Comment: So all sorted? Self answer or delete would be appropriate :)

Comment: I will self answer I guess because I could not find this solution described in this way, how did you see that it was a static method that caused the error? Could you describe it so I could create a detailed answer?

Comment: The big clue in your stack-trace was `System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for`. This indicates that static properties/constructors (that, by contract, ***must*** run **before** any instances can be new-ed up) have thrown errors.

Comment: @spender thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is to not have a static constructor in the DbContext or other static methods in constructor that is required to run before a new instance is created.

The big clue is in the stack-trace, **System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for...** This indicates that static properties/constructors (that, by contract, must run before any instances can be new-ed up) have thrown errors.
- Spender